# Using Only Single Quotes in a QuerySelector

Tags: javascript

I'm working with a Chrome Extension that uses querySelectors to scrape the DOM. The following querySelector properly returns my desired value (the last name in a full name) when entered into the Console:

```
document.querySelector('[data-bind="text: 
PersonName.fullName"]').textContent.slice(document.querySelector('[data- 
bind="text: PersonName.fullName"]').textContent.indexOf(" ")+1)
```

Within the Extension, however, these querySelectors are served up in a JSON object via an API, and the double-quotes cause a JSON parsing error. Is there an equivalent way to write the above query selector using only single quotes? Or to escape the double-quotes somehow such that JSON won't have an issue parsing it?

If you wish to test a potential answer, here's the HTML element that I'm attempting to scrape:

```
<span data-bind="text: PersonName.fullName">John Smith</span>
```

To add clarity - I don't have control over the HTML page, it is on the end user's machine.

Here's the generated JSON:

```
{"AtsMapping":[{"ID":"4"},{"atsCode":"ULT1"},{"atsName":"UltiPro"}, 
{"atsMapName":"UltiPro"},{"atsMapNotes":"John Smith (1)"}, 
{"firstName":"document.querySelector('[data-bind="text: 
PersonName.fullName"]').textContent.slice(0,document.querySelector('[data- 
bind="text: PersonName.fullName"]').textContent.indexOf(" "))"}, 
{"lastName":"document.querySelector('[data-bind="text: 
PersonName.fullName"]').textContent.slice(document.querySelector('[data- 
bind="text: PersonName.fullName"]').textContent.indexOf(" ")+1)"}, 
{"emailAddress":"document.querySelector(".email-address").innerText;"}, 
{"jobTitle":"document.querySelector('[data-bind="text: 
OpportunityTitle"]').textContent"},{"location":""},{"locationDefault":""}, 
{"effectiveDate":""},{"effectiveDateDefault":""},{"expirationDate":""}, 
{"expirationDateDefault":""},{"flsaStatus":""},{"flsaStatusDefault":""}, 
{"compGroup":""},{"compGroupDefault":""},{"benefitsGroup":""}, 
{"benefitsGroupDefault":""},{"offerTemplate":""},{"offerTemplateDefault":""}, 
{"confidentialFlag":""},{"confidentialFlagDefault":""}]}
```

And the error in parsing this JSON is:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token t in JSON at position 184
>       at JSON.parse ()
>       at Object.$.get [as success] (inject.js:10390)
>       at fire (inject.js:3274)
>       at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (inject.js:3404)
>       at done (inject.js:9311)
>       at XMLHttpRequest. (inject.js:9554)

Thanks!

Comment: Double quotes should be escaped when JSON encoded. What does the JSON look like?

Comment: You are setting javascript in JSON? seems like a bad idea

Comment: I agree, and am working with what I've been given. I can input the values that the API will return, and I can determine how the Chrome Extension handles them. I COULD alter the Extension to wrap the API values in the querySelector and other code, but then I'd potentially have to create a new Extension version every time we onboard a new client.

Comment: Use escape character to escape quotes, `document.querySelector('[data-bind=\'text: 
PersonName.fullName\']')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You  should escape the string.

See below how i converted your code to string and added it to json.

Make sure to se when i use `/"/"`

```js
var d= {"firstName": ""}

var value = "document.querySelector('[data-bind=\"text: PersonName.fullName\"]').textContent.slice(document.querySelector('[data- bind=\"text: PersonName.fullName\"]').textContent.indexOf(' ')+1)";

d.firstName = value;
console.log(d)
```

Comment: Perfect! Or close enough. Missing a space in the second `data-bind`. Thanks for your help, I was really struggling with this and was surprised no one offered this response! I will award the bounty ASAP, it says I have to wait 11 more hours. :)

Comment: NP glad i could help